# User access management in Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on moving my application to a cloud based database. Currently I have everything stored on the user's device in sqllite.

Once data is uploaded to the cloud, I'd like to allow my users to give access to their personal database to another person in order to synchronize between the two users.

Use Case:

Person 1 creates an account and begins to store data.  Person 1 wants to give person 2 access to their account. Person 2 logs in and the application determines person 2 has access to person 1's repo and the two client applications become synchronized to the same firestore collections as if they were logged in to the same account.

What is the best way to structure this? It would be easy enough to allow secondary users to access someone's personal documents but how do I do it in a way that my client application can easily determine what documents the secondary user has access to? Should I maintain another collection of user access maps?  How should I structure that?

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way that i can think of currently involved the Admin SDK of Firebase on your own server to grant custom claims to the target user who should get access to the said node.

Let's say

UID1 = user who wants to grant access

UID2 = user who will get the grant to access someone else's node

Here i will give you an idea about just the write rules, you can have the read public or the same or as you like

So the rules for UID1 node can be as (your structure can be as your needs, this is an example):

```
match /users/{UID1}/{allPaths=**}{

    allow write: if request.auth.uid == UID1 || request.auth.token.allowedAccesToId == UID1

}
```

This is thus a combination of the default user based rule and a custom claim rule

Here allowedAccesToId is a custom claim added via the admin sdk (JAVA) as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
claims.put("allowedAccesToId", UID1);
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setCustomUserClaimsAsync(UID2, claims).get();
```

You can see how to do it in other server side languages here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Now this will grant access to the UID2 user for a default duration of 1 hour, don't think you can customize the duration for the custom token any longer.

Once the user wants to revoke it, set the custom claim value of allowedAccesToId to some random value say xx which will never match any node. This way, the UID2 user won't be able to access the node of user1 anymore